# Centos7: How to configure apache with virtual hosts in a different location

Tags: apache

I've installed apache 2.4.6 in CENTOS7. By default apache locates all the DocumentRoot in `/var/www/html`.

I would like to locate my DocumentRoot at `/home/webs`.

My httpd.conf has next line

```
IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf
```

So I've include .conf files in `/etc/httpd/conf.d`

My .conf file is as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /home/webs/web1/
  ServerName web1.com
</VirtualHost>
```

but it doesn't run.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Your configuration may be wrong. Fix the configuration and make sure it contains a valid `<VirtualHost *>` and `</VirtualHost>` pair. SELINUX may be preventing apache from reading from `/home/webs/web1`. Modify context to allow apache to read from the directory.  ACL may be preventing apache from accessing the directory. Fix the ACL to allow apache. There may be boat loads of other possible issues. The best place to find what was causing the issue is to look at the apache error log.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just looking to change the location so you can easily drop your files into the webfolder from your home directory? If that is the case Why not keep the document root the same and create a symbolic link to the webfolder?

ln -s /var/www/html  /home/webs/web1